# Phase 10 Skip Card usage

Tags: phase-10

Can Skip Card be used if you have not laid down a phase?  Just like you can't lay down on someone without having laid down your phase yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can play a skip card anytime it's your turn to play. The rules don't make any connection between laying down a phase and playing a skip card.

> Draw a card from either the Draw Pile or the Discard Pile, and add it to your hand. And then, **discard any card that you want onto the Discard Pile**.

> Skip Card – This card enables you to force someone to skip or lose a turn for that particular rotation/round. Once you discard or play it down, you can choose anyone to lose their turn. The Skip card may not be picked up from the Discard Pile, only from the Draw Pile.

https://www.unorules.com/phase-10-rules/